# Сборщик мусора для .Net без stop-the-world пауз

Tags: производительность, .net, сборщик-мусора, jvm

Есть такая коммерческая виртуальная машина для Java, с гарантированным откликом и отсутствием остановок на сборку мусора, называется [Azul C4](http://www.javaspecialist.ru/2012/07/azul-c4.html) , хотелось б узнать есть ли реализация или аналог для .Net или Mono?

А если нет то сколько стоит? (интересует программная эмуляция, а не железка) Её вообще реально купить или это могут себе позволить только организации? А то я так и не нашел pricing.

Comment: Собрались писать игру на C#?

Comment: Нет, но ориентировочно heap в оперативной памяти будет всегда довольно большой (до 500Гб)

Comment: Во-первых, текущие версии GC в CLR собирает поколение 0 в фоновом режиме, без полной остановки потоков. Во-вторых, так ли это необходимо? Вполне возможно минимизировать выделения памяти в программе, как поступают при разработке игр, если это критично.

Comment: 500Гб ????

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам это необходимо? Почему бы просто пользоваться детерминистическим (ручным, через `Dispose`) освобождением памяти для критичных по размеру структур данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Investigating Real-Time Specifications for C#](http://wiki.epfl.ch/edicpublic/documents/Candidacy%20exam/flaviuwriteup.pdf)

> Nowadays, an increasing number of problems would
> benefit from solutions integrating the capabilities of both hard
> real-time and of normal, time-oblivious applications, running
> under the same environment. There is a need for abstractions
> and types, as well as a supporting virtual machine and memory
> management, which can provide guarantees for hard real-time
> tasks, while keeping the mainstream application running under
> the same Operating System transparent to the hard real-time
> features. In C# / .net environments, no frameworks or extensions
> have been created to address this need, the programmers
> currently have to take the challenge of specifying the realtime
> constraints into their own hands. The Real-Time Java
> Specification (RTSJ) has been an attempt to address part of
> these challenges, but it has brought up a number of problems
> related to the virtual machine and memory models.